# Poner un Timeout en mi script de PowerShell

Tags: script, powershell, timeout

os comento:

Necesito controlar que si un script en powershell que tengo, tarda mas de X horas en realizarse, se pare la ejecución del script.

Mi script básicamente llama a una función que basicamente hace control copy de la pantalla de un progama y analiza lo que sale.

La cosa es que si tarda mas de un tiempo determinado, significa que el programa del que se hace el control copy, ha fallado, y necesito que ese script pare y mande un correo para alertar del problema.

Despues de mucho buscar, no doy con una forma que funcione, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
#Tiempo en segundos que vamos a esperar hasta que finalicemos el Job
$Timeout = 10

#Iniciamos lo que queremos ejecutar
$Job = Start-Job `
    -ScriptBlock {#Código que queremos ejecutar
                  Get-service
                  } | Wait-Job -Timeout $Timeout

#Estado de la tarea
$Job.JobStateInfo.State
########################

#Si el job no ha terminado, lo paramos manualmente y abrimos incidencia
if ($Job.JobStateInfo.State -ne 'Completed')
{
Stop-Job -Job $Job

# Aquí mandaría el correo diciendo que el programa se ha colgado
}
else
{
#Recuperamos el resultado de la tarea
$results = Receive-Job -Job $Job 
$results
}
```

En donde dice "Código que queremos ejecutar" es donde yo pongo el código de mi script. Este código es la llamada a la función que es donde está toda la lógica para capturar la información de la pantalla del programa.

Los problemas del código de arriba son los siguentes:

Start-Job no me deja ir viendo en la terminal de powershell lo que va saliendo (esto me resulta muy util, aunque no es algo imprescindible) ya que ejecuta un job aparte del job principal (que sería el código de arriba).

Por otro lado, el script que hace el control copy no funciona si se lanza como job; el mensaje de error que devuelve el script cuando lo recupero en la variable "$result" es algo asi como que el clipboard solo se puede usar desde el hilo de proceso principal.
Este es el error concreto:

```
Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
```

Creo que la idea de lo que quiero hacer se vé en el código de arriba, pero no termino de ver como hacer para poder tener el timeout y a la vez ver pueda ir viendo lo que hace el script (o mejor dicho, lo que hace la funcion que es llamada por el script)...

A ver si me podeis echar una mano.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la poca experiencia que tengo, una manera de resolver podría ser la siguiente:

```
$timeoutSeconds = 2
$code = {
    #código
    0..950000 | ForEach-Object { $arr += $_ }
}
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code
#Si se completa en el tiempo definido
if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) {
    Write-host "Estado: " -NoNewline
    $job.JobStateInfo.State
#Si no se completa en el tiempo definido
} else {
    Write-host "No se ejecutó en el tiempo definido"
}
Remove-Job -force $job
```

En donde imprime el mensaje "*Estado: Completed*" si el job termina en tiempo y forma. De lo contrario, imprime en pantalla "*No se ejecutó en el tiempo definido*".

Comment: Esto es mas o menos lo que hago mas arriba... y no funciona... me sale el mismo error que a mi, en concreto este:
Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure 
that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

Comment: Que raro... a mi me funciona correctamente. Consulta: si usás el mismo bloque de código del ejemplo te generara el mismo error?

Comment: Si, si uso tu código, al igual que el que yo pongo en la pregunta principal, funciona, claro.
El problema es que lo que yo quiero controlar con el timeout es una función que usa el clipboard, asi que el método del Start-job parece que no funciona...

Comment: La pregunta fué porque encontré algo relacionado a eso, pero más del lado de C#. Por eso pregunté, porque se relacionaba el problema más a lo que se ejecutaba que al control del Job.

Comment: Te animas a compartir el código que se ejecuta en el job?

Comment: No puedo... en mi empresa son un poco tiquismiquis con esas cosas.

Comment: De todas formas, ya he encontrado la manera.
Lo que hago es lanzar un job que tiene un funcion a la que le paso como parametro el tiempo en minutos que le quiero dar a la ejecución, y la id del proceso en ejecución. Si se pasa ese tiempo, mata el porceso y manda correo

Comment: Te animas a compartir la solución y marcarla como respuesta? Así no queda la pregunta abierta! Gracias y me alegra que se haya encontrado la solución